# Chrome Kiosk Application Oauth

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, google-calendar-api, google-chrome-app

I have developed an application where there is a page that displays a users google calendar. I would like to set up the kiosk application to require a google sign-in. Additionally, I would like to use a variable in the calendars embed code that will call the current users calendar.

The application settings allow for me to use open ID to authenticate users. What exactly am I supposed to enter in the openID realm field?

Once that is set, will this code work to call the users calendar?

```
<script type="text/javascript>$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userinfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
$emailUser = $userinfo->getEmail();
print_r($emailUser);

$emailUserCal=str_replace ('@','%40',$emailUser);
print_r($emailUserCal);</script>

<?php echo '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=' . $emailUserCal . '&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Europe%2FParis" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>' ?>
```